# Browser crash after var_dump a variable

Tags: php

When I take content of a picture I try to dump it like that:

```
$filename = '(900).jpg';
$im = file_get_contents($filename);
var_dump(serialize($im));
```

When the picture is under 1mb everything works, but if it is more than 1mb browser crash can you tell me why is that a browser issue or some limitation of `file_get_contents()` function?

Comment: Are you using XDEBUG?

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: A simple echo might be more useful

Comment: I am trying to save that image info in the database but i don't recive any content of image files grater than 1mb because browser crash and i can't save it.

Comment: Var_dump has nothing to do with  saving a file to a db. Also  saving files to see DB is generally not recommended

Comment: Do You have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` turned on? Maybe `file_get_contents()` reports some error, that You don't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only limitation of `file_get_contents` might be the memory which is allowed for PHP to use. And the default is about 128 MB.

It is a browser "issue" if you want to call it that. Outputting so much debug information to the browser is not a good idea as you can see. Additionally there is no benefit in viewing a binary file as text.

If you want to find out if the variable is set, you can use functions to check the size of the (binary) string e.g. `mb_strlen()`.

A better way would be this

```
$filename = '(900).jpg';
$im = file_get_contents($filename);
// check if the file could be loaded
if ($im !== false) {
    // start your processing
}
```

But this does not check what kind of file you have loaded into the string. If you must store the file into the database - which is considered very evil - you can either store the binary string into a BLOB type row or encode the binary string with `base64_encode()` and store it into a text type. Both of this solutions are also not recommended!

If you need to store image information into the database, you should think about using references to the files - e.g. the file path. Your primary objective is to secure that the database information and the filesystem information is always synchronized.

Comment: Thank you i will use it that way.